# How to use Chi-square test in dataset with negative values

Tags: machine-learning, python, optimization

I could not fully explain the title. In order to use the Chi-square test in my dataset, I am finding the smallest value and add each cell with that value. (for example, the range of data here is [-8,11] so I added +8 to each cell and the range turned to [0,19]).

dataValues variable is DataFrame type that holds my all data and contains ~2000 features, ~1000 rows, dataTargetEncoded variable is Array type that contains results as 0 and 1.

```
for i in range(len(dataValues.index)):
    for j in range(len(dataValues.columns)):
        dataValues.iat[i, j] += 8

#fit chi2 and get results
bestfeatures = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k="all")
fit = bestfeatures.fit(dataValues, dataTargetEncoded)
feat_importances = pd.Series(fit.scores_, index=dataValues.columns)

#print top 10 feature
print(feat_importances.nlargest(10).index.values)

# back to normal
for i in range(len(dataValues.index)):
    for j in range(len(dataValues.columns)):
        dataValues.iat[i, j] -= 8
```

But this causes performance problems. Another solution I'm thinking of is to normalize it. I wrote a function that looks like this:

```
def normalization(df):
    from sklearn import preprocessing

    x = df.values  # returns a numpy array
    min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
    df = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled, columns=df.columns)

return df
```

My program has accelerated lots, but this time my accuracy has decreased. The feature selection process I have done with the first method produces 0.85 accuracy results, this time I am producing 0.70 accuracy.

I want to get rid of this primitive method, but I also want accuracy to remain constant. How do I proceed? Thank you in advance

Comment: I do not understand why chi2 would require non negative values in the first place- maybe you can ellaborate?

Comment: There is an answer for: https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-chi-squared-be-calculated-on-negative-values

Comment: Since you're using pandas, perhaps the built-in handling of such operations would be faster than custom iteration? Have you tried something along the lines of: `df - df.min()`? The value of `df.min()` can be stored for later inverse transformation like: `df + df_min`.

Comment: Im sorry I didnt get it. Can you give me an example If you dont mind?

Comment: But the problem is Im not sure if its best way to handle this problem to summing all values with 8

Comment: No worries. My previous comment is unrelated to the actual topic of the question (I hastily jumped in with suggestions) and relates only to the performance issues you were experiencing with custom iteration in your code. You are right that "shifting" the values is not the solution, since the chi-squared test works with a contingency table that is based on your data, not the actual data itself.

Comment: You can use [pd.crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to calculate a contingency table from your data, then use that for the chi-squared test. Negative values in your data are not a problem, but the data should be discrete (integers, categories, etc)

Comment: Sadly my dataset is not discrete (It consists of very small spaced float type numbers like 1.157, 1.268, 2.56 etc.) and even I use this function I dont know how to integrate to my code.

Comment: You can always bin your continuous data into discrete intervals by using [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html). Perhaps [this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/chi-squared-test-for-machine-learning/) will help you understand how the chi-squared test can be applied to your data. If it doesn't help, please update the question with your latest code and I'll attempt to answer it.

Comment: I didnt get it how to implement pd.cut. Updated my all code with comments. If you dont mind can you take a look?

Comment: Of course, I'll try to be as thorough as I can in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, it does not matter to the chi-square test whether your data is positive, negative, string or any other type, as long as it is discrete (or nicely binned). This is due to the fact that the chi-square test calculations are based on a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table#Example) and *not* your raw data. The documentation of [sklearn.feature_selection.chi2](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html) and the related [usage example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#univariate-feature-selection) are not clear on that at all. Not only that, but the two are not in concord regarding the type of input data (documentation says booleans or frequencies, whereas the example uses the raw iris dataset, which has quantities in centimeters), so this causes even more confusion. The reason why sklearn's chi-squared expects only non-negative features is most likely the [implementation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f6924/sklearn/feature_selection/univariate_selection.py#L224): the authors are relying on a row-by-row sum, which means that allowing negative values will produce the wrong result. Some hard-to-understand optimization is happening internally as well, so for the purposes of simple feature selection I would personally go with [scipy's implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html).

Since your data is not discrete, you will have to bin every feature into *some* number of nominal categories in order to perform the chi-squared test. Be aware that information loss takes place during this step regardless of your technique; your aim is to minimize it by finding an approach that best suits your data. You must also understand that the results cannot be taken as the absolute truth since the test is not designed for data of continuous nature. Another massive problem that will *definitely* mess with your feature selection process in general is that the number of features is larger than the number of observations. I would definitely recommend taking a look at [sklearn's decomposition methods](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.decomposition) such as PCA to reduce the number of features, and if your features come in groups, you can try Multiple Factor Analysis (Python implementation available via [prince](https://github.com/MaxHalford/prince#multiple-factor-analysis-mfa)).

Now that that's out of the way, let's go through an example of simple feature selection using the iris dataset. We will add a useless normally distributed variable to the constructed dataframe for comparison.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import pandas as pd

from sklearn import datasets, preprocessing as prep

iris = datasets.load_iris()

X, y = iris['data'], iris['target']
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns= iris['feature_names'])
df['useless_feature'] = np.random.normal(0, 5, len(df))
```

Now we have to bin the data. For value-based and quantile-based binning, you can use [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and [pd.qcut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html), respectively (this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211923/what-is-the-difference-between-pandas-qcut-and-pandas-cut) explains the difference between the two), but sklearn's [KBinsDiscretizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer.html) provides even more options. Here I'm using it for one-dimensional [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Algorithms) to create the bins (separate calculation for each feature):

```
def bin_by_kmeans(pd_series, n_bins):
    binner = prep.KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins= n_bins, encode= 'ordinal', strategy= 'kmeans')
    binner.fit(pd_series.values.reshape(-1, 1))
    bin_edges = [
        '({:.2f} .. {:.2f})'.format(left_edge, right_edge)
        for left_edge, right_edge in zip(
            binner.bin_edges_[0][:-1],
            binner.bin_edges_[0][1:]
        )
    ]
    return list(map(lambda b: bin_edges[int(b)], binner.transform(pd_series.values.reshape(-1, 1))))

df_binned = df.copy()
for f in df.columns:
    df_binned[f] = bin_by_kmeans(df_binned[f], 5)
```

A good way to investigate how well your individual features are binned is by counting the number of data points in each bin (`df_binned['feature_name_here'].value_counts()`) and by printing out a [pd.crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) (contingency table) of the given feature and label columns.

> An often quoted guideline for the validity of this calculation is that the test should be used only if the observed and expected frequencies in each cell are at least 5.

So the **more zeroes** you see in the contingency table, the **less accurate** the chi-squared results will be. This will require a bit of manual tuning.

Next comes the function that performs the chi-squared test for independence on two variables ([this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/chi-squared-test-for-machine-learning/) has very useful explanations, highly recommended read, code is pulled from there):

```
def get_chi_squared_results(series_A, series_B):
    contingency_table = pd.crosstab(series_A, series_B)
    chi2_stat, p_value, dof, expected_table = sp.stats.chi2_contingency(contingency_table)
    threshold = sp.stats.chi2.ppf(0.95, dof)
    return chi2_stat, threshold, p_value
```

The values to focus on are the statistic itself, the threshold, and its p-value. The threshold is obtained from a [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function). You can use these three to make the final assessment of individual feature-label tests:

```
print('{:<20} {:>12} {:>12}\t{:<10} {:<3}'.format('Feature', 'Chi2', 'Threshold', 'P-value', 'Is dependent?'))
for f in df.columns:
    chi2_stat, threshold, p_value = get_chi_squared_results(df[f], y)
    is_over_threshold = chi2_stat >= threshold
    is_result_significant = p_value <= 0.05
    print('{:<20} {:>12.2f} {:>12.2f}\t{:<10.2f} {}'.format(
        f, chi2_stat, threshold, p_value, (is_over_threshold and is_result_significant)
    ))
```

In my case, the output looks like this:

```
Feature                      Chi2    Threshold  P-value    Is dependent?
sepal length (cm)          156.27        88.25  0.00       True
sepal width (cm)            89.55        60.48  0.00       True
petal length (cm)          271.80       106.39  0.00       True
petal width (cm)           271.75        58.12  0.00       True
useless_feature            300.00       339.26  0.46       False
```

In order to claim dependence between the two variables, the resulting statistic should be larger than the threshold value **and** the [p-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value#Definition_and_interpretation) should be lower than 0.05. You can choose smaller p-values for higher confidence (you'd have to calculate the threshold from `sp.stats.chi2.ppf` accordingly), but 0.05 is the "largest" value needed for your results to be considered significant. As far as ordering of useful features goes, consider looking at the relative magnitude of the difference between the calculated statistic and the threshold for each feature.

Comment: One of the best answers I have ever seen. Thank you so much. I am reading over and over again for understand every detail. Thank you but seems you answered my one question but now I have lots of questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Chi-Sqaured statistic is a square of Z-statistic so I don't understand why it would matter if you have negative values in there.

Comment: I didnt write to calculation of chi-square value. Im using Scikit-learn library for that and when I try to implement in this line :  fit = bestfeatures.fit(dataValues, dataTargetEncoded) it returns me error that dataValues can not contains negavite values. Also there is an answer for that: https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-chi-squared-be-calculated-on-negative-values

Comment: What I was trying to say is; since the chi-squared statistic is square of Z it will always have only positive values.

Comment: Hmm Im not sure but observed values cannot be negative because (Observed - Expected)^2/Expected in this formula if the observed value is negative, we find the sum of the expected value not the difference from the expected value.